# pipe ffmpeg output in another program with timestamp

Tags: ffmpeg

I know how to pipe the ffmpeg raw_video output into my program to perform some baseband processing but how can we do that and pass to the program the timestamp of each frame.

For example, if I write:

```
fmpeg  -i input stream.ts -f rawvideo -an - | myprog -w 320 -h 240 -f 24.0 >> output.yuv
```

I just receive each frame sequentially and I suppose that their time interval are constant and is 1/24 seconds.

to provide the real timestamp when using a video file, I can first use ffprobe to extract time info, like below and provide the pts file to my program as an additional parameter.

```
ffprobe –show_frames –select_streams v:0 input.ts | grep pkt_pts_time= >> output.pts
```

But can we ask ffmpeg to dump the whole decoding sample including its informations ?